# option menu not clicked at first time in sherlockfragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, optionmenu

I have used option menu in my fragment.The problem is that when i go first time to fragment ,the option menu click event is not called.But when i go to another fragment.and again revist that fragment then the option menu click event is called...
following is the code

```
    //Creating the option menu
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) 
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.newcarmenu, menu);

    }

@Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{        
    //super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);             

  switch(item.getItemId())
   { 
     case R.id.menuNewCar:
         _menuClickCallback.onMenuSelected();
         break;
   }
   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
```

please tell me why this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you are returning `super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)` every time, so the selection is being passed on. You need to `return true` when your `MenuItem` has been selected. Try this instead:

```
switch(item.getItemId())
{ 
  case R.id.menuNewCar:
    _menuClickCallback.onMenuSelected();
    return true;
  default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```